# Calculating the likehood from the coeficients of logistical regression

Tags: logistic, python, scikit-learn, gamma-distribution

I am doing a logistical regression and need to calculate the likehood from the null model and from each feature model and to after that get the p-value.The problem states:

a) Create a model that contains only the intercept (null model), i.e. no features are considered.

b) Create multiple models each considering a single feature. Note that
famhist is a categorical feature which has to be converted to numbers first.

c) Create a function likelihood_ratio_test implementing the likelihood-ratio
test which takes the log-likelihood of the full model and the reduced model
(D= −2 log (likelihood reduced model / likelihood full model). Use this function to compare the single feature models to the null model. Which feature yields the most significant improvement over the null model?

And what i did was:

```
score= np.zeros((100,1))
for i in range (0,100):
    Xtrain,Xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25)
    lr.fit(X,y)
    score[i] = lr.score(Xtest,ytest)
print(score.mean())
print(score.std())
```

That gaves me : `0.732931034483 and 0.0410724976043`

and the coeficients:

```
lr.coef_[0]

array([ -1.64117275e-03,   8.13831831e-02,   1.63686039e-01,
         4.67454831e-02,   8.65711061e-01,   2.10749204e-02,
        -1.29359397e-01,  -2.94734585e-05,   3.37944408e-02])

lr.intercept_

array([-2.38171075])
```

But now I am stuck, how should I use these coeficients to build the likehood how to compute them ? Why do I need to do a model to the intercept, wouldnt I just get a line ?
To get the p-value as stated before.
I intend to user the scipy.special.gammaincc(df/2, D/2) function.